# Simple app - angular is not defined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, intellij-idea

I am just beginning to learn javascript and angularjs using

https://thinkster.io/mean-stack-tutorial

I set up a basic IntelliJ javascript project and created the following files

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>My Angular App!</title>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="app.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="HelloWorld" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
        <div>
            {{test}}
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and app.js

```
var app = angular.module('HelloWorld', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', [
  '$scope',
  function($scope){
    $scope.test = 'Hello world!';
  }]);
```

but I keep getting "ReferenceError: angular is not defined" when I attempt to run the program. Searching through the other questions on this website most of the answers involve the

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.10/angular.min.js">
```

line being called after app.js is started, which I don't think is the problem here. Can anyone give some insight for a complete beginner?

Comment: Are you including Angular's source code in a script element BEFORE you're calling it?

Comment: Did you check the console for errors? perhaps the angular script fails to load?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to comment directly, but I'm not a power user enough... so I'll go here!

What yarons mean, was use the developer apps in your browser (please not IE) and check the output in the console and also in the console where your Node app is running.

Two suggestions here:

1. Are the dependencies correctly set in your application? Check your
   package.json file, find the angular tag and check whether there
   might be a version conflict.
2. Copy the following files from */node-modules/angular* in
   */public/libs/angular* and set your script ref in your **index.html** to

   - angular.min.js
   - angular.min.js.map
   - angular-csp.css

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Note that the most common way is to use the libs from CDN, but there are reasons to keep them locally...